# C++ / Node.js :binding.gyp library fails

Tags: c++, node.js, unresolved-external, node.js-addon

I've created a C++ program on Windows 7 in Visual Studio 2015 which uses EnumProcessModules.
When I compile it in VS2015 it succeeds.

Now, I created an C++ addon in Node.js which includes the above code (EnumProcessModules).

when I compile it from command line (by running **node-gyp build**), I get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'psapi.dll' [C:\Users\Yoni\W
ebstormProjects\my_prog\build\getProcesses.vcxproj]
```

psapi.dll exists at

```
C:\Users\Yoni\WebstormProjects\my_prog\
```

I took it from `C:\Windows\System32\`

And this is my binding.gyp code:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "getProcesses",
      "sources": [ "psInfo.cc", "json.hpp" ],
      "libraries": [ "psapi.dll" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to resolve this?

Thx for the help.

Comment: Are you linking with the correct library in your binding.gyp?

Comment: @mscdex well i've added psapi.dll in my binding.gyp but i'm still getting an error (see updated question) thx!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to use `"psapi.lib"` instead of `"psapi.dll"` in your `"libraries"` list.